# DataGrid - Edit the selected row when a button is clicked

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, itemrenderer, itemeditor

I have a very simple DataGrid with 2 columns, some thing like this:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="grid" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="date" headerText="Date"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

What Im trying to do is to activate the edition of the selected row when the user clicks a button. So far I've been unable to find any example of how to do this. I already tried 6 or 7 different approaches but non works. Does any one has a clue how to do this?

How do you get the selected row (NOT selectedItem) of a DataGrid and how can you:

- Change the ItemRenderEditor or ItemRenderer on the fly of just that row.
- Or enable the edition of that specific row without clicking it.

This are the questions that I've been unable to answer

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the selected row with the grid.selectedIndex property. One thought to you problem:

- Add an "editable" property to you items in the datagrid which is false by default
- When clicking on the button, set grid.selectedItem.editable = true;
- Change the grid's item renderer to a new one, which displays TextInput fields if an item is editable or just plain Label if it's not

You can change the item renderer at runtime like this:

```
grid.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(com.myapp.renderers.MyGridItemRenderer);
```